# How to get sequelize.ARRAY internal datatype

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, postgresql-9.1, sequelize-cli

Node seqeulize supports the postgres ARRAY type.
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html#static-variable-DataTypes

Say :

```
    nameVariations: {
      type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING),
      allowNull: true,
    }
```

Let's assume this model is called city.

When looking at the city model, we will see an attribute called nameVaritions of type "ARRAY", but I couldn't find a way in seqeulzie to find what is the array internal type (in this case Seqeulize.STRING).

How can that be achieved in seqeulize? Is there a way to read the internal type from the seqeuzlie model or model instance?

The following image shows what I currently have available on the model attribute:
[image: This is all I have available on the model object, no mentioned of internal datatype...]